# Php 7.2 class property tha contians array of objects

Tags: php, arrays, object

I'm using php 7.2.
I need to instantiate an object of a class with a property that have to contain an array of objects.
When I try to add elements to array, I get an "**Array to string conversion**" error.
this is the code example:

```
class MyProduct
{
    public $id;
    public $stocks = array();
}

class MyStock
{
    public $quantity;
    public $leadTime;
}

private function Test()
{
    $prod = new \MyProduct();
    $prod->id = 1;

    $stock1 = new \MyStock();
    $stock1->quantity = 10;
    $stock1->leadTime = 2;

    array_push($prod->$stocks,  $stock1);
}
```

How can I make it?
thanks in advance

Comment: Is that private function inside one of the classes? Doesn't look like it would work at all the way it is here. Or is the 'private' just a typo?

Comment: `$prod->$stocks,`, it can only be `$prod->stocks`

Comment: Yes, this ^^. But really you don't need `array_push()` for this. You should use `$prod->stocks[] = $stock`.

Comment: also, method(functions) can be `private, public or protected` `ONLY inside class`, so in your case ether you will put method Test() inside class, or remove word `private`. Learn OOP this is really bad

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `array_push($prod->stocks,  $stock1);`
With `$stocks` you’re trying to refer to a variable called stocks.